# How to select a <tr> from the same data index as a scatterplot <circle>

Tags: d3.js, html-table

and thank you for any help on this. I've read many posts, but still can't quite get the connection between the dataTable and the scatterplot circles to be in sync, so that when rollover one the other also highlights.  I tried Mike Bostock's tutorials (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/  very helpful) to get this far.  I have the circles highlight on rollover, and I can get the 1st table row to highlight, but can't figure out the nested reference needed to get the table rows to respond from [index].  ANY help is very appreciated!  Thank you.

```
  json data for reference is 
 {
   "aaData": [
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Ball Hull",
    "section": "History 1 A",
    "overallScore": 99,
    "overallProgress": 16
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Brewer Holden",
    "section": "English 1 B",
    "overallScore": 75,
    "overallProgress": 83
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Briana Can",
    "section": "English 1 B",
    "overallScore": 56,
    "overallProgress": 100,
}]}




        svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset.aaData)
        .style("stroke-width", "2")
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        d3.select("tbody").selectAll("tr").style("color", function(d, i) { return i ? null : "red"; });
         d3.select(this).style({'stroke-width':4, 'stroke':'red'})
        ;})

         .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
         d3.select("tbody").selectAll("tr").style("color", function(d, i) { return i ? null : "blue"; });
         d3.select(this).style({'stroke-width':'2', 'stroke':null})
         ;})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mouseover function, I renamed your `d` and `i` variables to make things more clear, and more importantly to avoid variable "collision", since `d` and `i` are associated with different things in the outer function's scope than the inner function's.

```
.on("mouseover", function(dCircle, iCircle) {
  d3.select("tbody").selectAll("tr")
    .style("color", function(dTr, iTr) {
      return iCircle == iTr ? "red" : null;
    });
    d3.select(this).style({'stroke-width':4, 'stroke':'red'});
 });
```

The crucial line, `return iCircle == iTr ? "red" : null;` assumes that the `<tr>` corresponding to the hovered circle has the same index in the data array as the circle itself. I'm pretty sure that's true in your case, assuming you're binding the same `"aaData"` array to the `<tr>`s (not shown). So this should work. But if it doesn't –– or just to be safer and arguably more appropriate –– you can base the check for the matching `<tr>` on the data itself, rather than the index. So, instead of `iCircle == iTr`, you could say:

```
dCircle == dTr
```

or

```
dCircle.id == dTr.id
```